# Sequence of simple functions converging uniformly to $f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Let $(X,A)$ be a measurable space and $f:(X,A) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ be a non-negative bounded function.

Prove there exists a sequence of non-negative simple functions $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Big(\sup_{x \in X}\big|f_{n}(x) - f(x)\big|\Big) = 0$.

Attempt:

We know that for a non-negative function $f:(X, A) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ we can find a monotone sequence, i.e. $f_{n}(x) \leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x \in X$ so that for all $x \in X$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_{n}(x) = f(x)$$

For example via the typewriter sequence.

**This next part is where I am a bit unsure**:

Since this sequence of functions is increasing its limit is the supremum. Therefore for some $n \geq N$ $\sup_{x \in X}\Big|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\Big|\Big) = 0$. Hence by taking the limit the result follows.

Comment: The standard construction of $f_n$'s increasing to $f$ (as in Rudin) is good enough.

Comment: "for some $n \geq N$ $\sup_{x \in X}\Big|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\Big| = 0$" -- This is only possible if $f$ is simple, which won't necessarily be true; even if $f$ is simple, it may be false.

Comment: Thanks to both, any suggestions on how I amend my proof to be correct? If I take just standard construction of $f_{n}$'s increasing to $f$ then of course I know that the pointwise limit exists but I don't know how to then say that it is uniform.

Comment: I believe the standard definition is $f_n(x) = 2^{-n} \lfloor 2^n f(x)\rfloor$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\leq x$.  What is an upper bound for $f(x) - f_n(x)$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Got it! Thanks.